# HTTPS url not working but same HTTP working

Tags: azure, iis

I have created a webapi and published it on Azure. I have installed ssl certificate on this.

When I am accessing this using http (http://myapi.com/firstendpoint) its returning me the the data but when I am trying to access it using https (https://myapi.com/firstendpoint) its saying HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

I checked the certificate at browser by clicking lock button on left side of url and its showing me correct certificate so I am assuming certificate linking is working.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, but I suggest you can check the service plan. If you want to bind a custom SSL certificate (a third-party certificate or App Service certificate) to your web app, your App Service plan must be in the Basic, Standard, Premium, or Isolated tier. And Custom SSL is not supported in the F1 or D1 tier. For more details about custom SSL, see [Bind an existing custom SSL certificate to Azure Web Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-ssl).

**Update**

With the update, it means you install the web app in the Azure VM. So you should allow the traffic with the port 443 for HTTPS in the NSG of the VM.

Comment: I think binding is all correct as I can see the certificate at browser, only thing is not working when https is used. working OK if http. Can it be something related to IP, do I need to assign IP instead of all unassigned in binding at IIS

Comment: What do you mean assign IP? Which type do you choose to bind the certificate?

Comment: please see the image at description, i have edited that

Comment: It seems that you deploy the Web API inside Azure VM. For this condition, you should check if the firewall blocks the traffic on port 443 both in the windows vm and Azure NSG.

Comment: @AnkeshKumar Does the solution help you solve the problem? Please let me know the message. I also can provide more help if you need.

Comment: @AnkeshKumar I will add it to the answer, you can accept it.